# First iOS app for all iphone devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode7

I'm trying to make my first iOS app in xcode 7 for iOS 9
and i want to make it for all the iphone devices like iphone 4,4s,5,5s,6.

Do i have to make a different xib file for each one of the iphone or there is a simple way to make it for EVERY iOS device also like iPad???

Comment: Two terms, autolayout and universal app. This is a basic thing which you can easily find on google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a magical thing called autolayout. And another thing called universal app

Answer (score 1):

You Can do both in single storyboard first you have to choose Universal while creating project. You need to do autoresize or apply auto layout.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't need to do device or resolution detection. iOS includes lots of features for adaptive user interfaces. See here for example: https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Answer (score 1):

You just use auto layout concept in your application and you will find lots of document on net for auto layout and re sizing class.

Answer (score 1):

You can make one app for all device using autolayout and make your app universal and in xcode 7 and ios 9 there is new feature available stack view using this you can do this.